# Importing classes from same folder in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from .MessageReceiver import MessageReceiver
from .MessageParser import MessageParser
```

I just get `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Made a **init**.py file as well (God knows why that's even necessary)

What is this nonsense? How hard should it be to do a simple import? All my google searches turn up indecipherable wall-text garbage.

What words do I put where to do a simple import?

Comment: simple add your path to python_path and try ``from MessageReceiver import MessageReceiver``

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is python_path?

Comment: You don't need to create `__init__.py` when importing from same directory. Assuming the filename where `MessageReceiver` class defined is `MessageReceiver.py` then simply use `from MessageReceiver import MessageReceiver` (without a `.`) http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language/9222/creating-a-module#t=201703080454303586326